# Chef Omnibus: run export PATH=/opt/rumm/embedded/bin:$PATH after package install

Tags: chef-infra

We have an Chef Omnibus package that installs a gem-based command line tool. How do we run a script after Omnibus unpacks? I want to be able to add the omnibus embdded/bin to PATH.

Comment: OS specific.... In Linux this is easiest done by creating a profile file.

Comment: Can you provide more information about this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux you use `package-scripts/<project>/postinst` and `package-scripts/<project>/postrm`. On OSX, you use `package-scripts/<project>/makeselfinst`.

And add this line:

`ln -sf $DEST_DIR/embedded/bin/<project>/usr/bin || error_exit "Cannot link <project> to /usr/bin"`

Make sure you have DEST_DIR defined:

`DEST_DIR=/opt/<project>`